# PayPal donate button code glitch (CSS/HTML)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add PayPal donate buttons to my website, but for some reason, the code makes random invisible links in the top left near my navbar / "about" button. When I try to click there it will bring up the PayPal donation screen. The website is pumpkinchugger.github.io/rona20.live - I don't have the button on the website but you can see where it is supposed to go when clicking in the top right. Here is the PayPal code for the buttons:

Could it be a problem with trying to put the buttons in the popup?

Comment: Are you using PayPal's smart buttons?

Comment: Yes they are the smart buttons